# How to search for any lines that exist in only one of two text files?

Tags: text, comparison

I am trying to compare two files and find the lines that only exist in one of the files.

I have tried using FC in windows command prompt but the lines could be anywhere in the file and so this is not working for me.

Example files:

```
File 1:
Two
Five
One
Four
Three
```

```
File 2:
One
Three
Four
Five
```

The output for this example should just be

```
Two
```

Edit: The actual files I am trying to analyze are a lot more complicated and could have multiple repeats of each string within each file so I cannot just sort both files and then compare them. The context of this issue is that I have an old list of strings and a new list of strings and I am trying to find all of the strings that have been added since the old list was created.

Comment: Concatenate the files then iterate through them, searching through the rest of the file for each line and outputting if not found twice. But really, this question as written is too broad since you haven't specified which programming language you want to use.

Comment: @EvanM I cannot do that because it is likely that lines occur many times within a file if they occur at all. I would likely have no output at all. I don't really have a preference for what language to use, honestly I was just expecting to do it with command prompt, though I don't even know if that is possible.